# How to copy entire harddrive of a computer to a file while running a live USB

Tags: linux, usb, backup

I am running on a live session of linux on my USB. I am seeking to copy the entire contents on my hard drive to a file on a external USB.

To the best of my knowledge, using the **dd** command on the mounted directory of the harddrive will copy all of its contents, but will also repartition the USB, which i dont want. I still have files on the exteral USB i used for backing up on other PC's.

To the best of my knowledge, issuing the **cp -r** command on the mounted directory will copy files, without partitioning, but fail to include hidden files.

What is the proper command i need to copy the entire hardrive to a file for backup?

Comment: "but will also repartition the USB" What.

Comment: dd command copies the partition structure of the target to the best of my knowledge. This would not create single backup Directory of the hard drive to the best of my knowledge

Comment: But... the target is a file...

Comment: You can not use `dd` on a directory.  You use it on the device node representing the raw disk or partition, while it is not mounted.  The destination should be a file on the mounted external disk, not the device node representing that disk, which would do as you say.  The destination of course, needs to be large enough to hold the whole source disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe dd to a gzip file:

([source](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image))

`# dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /mnt/sda1/hda.img.gz`

See also :
[Why is piping 'dd' through gzip so much faster than a direct copy?](https://superuser.com/questions/760097/why-is-piping-dd-through-gzip-so-much-faster-than-a-direct-copy)